# Check if a field a included in a Matrix block

Tags: templating, matrix, craft3

Situation: I have a matrix with about 10 block types, 3 of which have a certain field. I want to check if the current block has that field.

The field in question is a dropdown with values in all 3 options.

I've tried:

- `{{ attribute(block, 'backgroundColor') is defined ? 'true' : 'false' }}`

=>  returns `true` for all blocks

- `{% if block.backgroundColor|length %}`

=> errors out with `Craft\MatrixBlockModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "backgroundColor".`

- `{% if block.backgroundColor is defined %}`

=> same error as above

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Checking if the field is defined should work. Is it the missing "d" in this line? {% if block.backgroun**d**Color is defined %}

Comment: Have you tried `{% if block['backgroundColor'] is defined %}` this might not make any sense since it's actually "wrong" (PHP wise)  but Twig has a rare bug in certain cases and doesn't recognize the correct syntax properly

Comment: @RobinSchambach That seems to be working! Could you post it as the answer? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In certain cases Twig is unable to recognize the correct object oriented syntax with magic properties so `{% if object.property is defined %}` will still produce an error.

You can use `{% if block['backgroundColor'] is defined %}` it seems strange and would usually considered as wrong syntax (PHP wise) but it works in Twig